# What does this music CAPTCHA mean?

Tags: terminology

[image: Capture music]

> Select all images where if you were to add a decrescendo it would add
> to the musicality of the piece without being interpreted as an overly
> heavy-handed metaphor within the context of the thematic material.

I have two questions:

1. What does that mean
2. What is the solution?

Comment: I'd love to know what site that's from. Presumably it's a joke CAPTCHA.

Comment: Yes, this is just a joke; it's attempting to give you an impossible decision to proceed forward through the CAPTCHA. There is no right answer, and so unfortunately I'm going to have to close the question. Thanks for the laugh, though!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the premise of the question is flawed.

Comment: Pretty sure it’s just a joke because it’s hilarious

Comment: I'm anxious to find out which charts should be selected.

Comment: Fukai Mizumi, do you understand the joke now? (If not, I think an answer is actually possible here, explaining why the Captcha is clearly a joke based on the highly subjective nature of the criteria...)

Comment: I personally suspect the answer varies depending on the *size* of the decrescendo - one that spans the *entire length of the sheet music*, for example, must be interpreted as deliberate and (somehow) adding to musicality. Be lucky that the typical reaction to getting your first CAPTCHA wrong is that the software presents another CAPTCHA to you.